# Google Signin from server side app in ruby

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-signin, google-oauth, google-api-ruby-client

I have a mobile app that is signin in with google and sending a server auth code to my backend app.
I want to use this code, along with the client secrets from the google developer console, to retrieve a refresh code for retrieving data from google drive when the user is offline.

Google provides an [client](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby) for auth calls in ruby, but it seems not to be maintained lately and I could not see a way to do this kind of authorisation in the docs.
In the documentation, I could find an example of how to do this on python:

```
from oauth2client import client

# Exchange auth code for access token, refresh token, and ID token
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'profile', 'email'],
    auth_code)
```

I would like to do this in ruby through a post to their `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` endpoint. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = URI("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true    

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri, headers)

request.body = {
    code: "#{server_auth_code_sent_to_api}",
    client_id: "#{client_id_from_developer_console}",
    client_secret: "#{client_secret_from_developer_console}",
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    redirect_url: '',
}.to_json

response = http.request(request)
puts JSON.parse(response.read_body)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
{
 "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
 "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

Does anybody has an idea on what I'm doing wrong, or has a working example on how to do this kind of authorisation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody stumbles here with a similar problem, what caused the request to fail was the `Content-Type`, and not the `grant_type` parameter.
Digging around in the code for the client library I saw that they use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the endpoint expects a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. I adjusted my code accordingly and was able to get a successful response with the valid credentials and token.
Here follows the resulting code:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = URI("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")

params = {
    "code" => "#{server_auth_code_sent_to_api}",
    "client_id" => "#{client_id_from_developer_console}",
    "client_secret" => "#{client_secret_from_developer_console}",
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "redirect_url" => "#{redirect_url_from_developer_console}",
}

response = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, params)

puts JSON.parse(response.read_body)
```